# Getting an error on with my code on apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[UserCodeAppPanel Error(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNyuI.png)

I am using SpreadsheetApp to show location within a radius from the spreadsheet and I am getting this error. Could someone assist me with what is wrong in my code in order to fix this error?

Below is my code in the Index.html file using google sheets app script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Draw Circles using Google Map API</title> 
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyArRKMKMbDrCz1h1KKpKbfqOfzNGfZiT_o"></script>
    <!--PLEASE NOTE: As of June 22 2016, Google Maps require an API key.
    * GET YOUR API KEY FROM ... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
    * ONCE YOU GET THE KEY, REPLACE 'js?sensor=false' IN THE ABOVE URL WITH "js?key=YOUR_NEW_API_KEY".--> 
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapContainer" style="width:750px;height:350px;"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
  
    // LOCATION IN LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE. 
    function onFormSubmit(event) {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        // MAP ATTRIBUTES
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(33.6608243, -84.4954219);
        var mapAttr = {
            center: center,
            zoom: 10,

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // THE MAP TO DISPLAY.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapAttr);
    

        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: center,
            map: map,
            radius: 16093.40,          // IN METERS.
            fillColor: '#FF6600',
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
            strokeWeight: 0,        // DON'T SHOW CIRCLE BORDER.
            content:'<h1>Atlanta Community Food FoodBank</h1>'
  
        });  

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:{lat:33.6608243, lng:-84.4954219},
        map:map,
        icon: 'https://img.icons8.com/fluent/48/000000/marker.png',
        draggable: false
        });

        var information = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<h4>Atlanta Community Food Bank</h4>'
        }); 

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          information.open(map, marker);
        })

        var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
        var markers = "coords:[{lat:"+ss.getRange('D2').getValue()+", "+"lng:"+ss.getRange('E2').getValue()+"}]";
        
        
     
        for(var i = 1; i < markers.length; i++){
          addMarker(markers[i]);
        }

        function addMarker(props){
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:props.coords,
            map:map,
          })
        }

    }
   
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', onFormSubmit);
</script>
</html>
```

I want to show location inside and outside of radius from the latitude and longitude on spreadsheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM4kx.png)

Code.gs
[Code.gs File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd0sK.png)

[UserCodeAppPanel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxjjY.png)

Comment: onFormSubmit is a google apps script server side event.

Comment: Same is true about SpreadsheetApp

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you replace the following line of code first. Or simply delete.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

With

```
// var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Second replace the follow code.

```
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
var markers = "coords:[{lat:"+ss.getRange('D2').getValue()+", "+"lng:"+ss.getRange('E2').getValue()+"}]";
        
        
     
for(var i = 1; i < markers.length; i++){
  addMarker(markers[i]);
}

function addMarker(props){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position:props.coords,map:map,
   })
}
```

With

```
function addMarker(props){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:props.coords,
    map:map,
  })
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
  function(markers) {
    for(var i = 1; i < markers.length; i++) {
      addMarker(markers[i]);
    }
  }
).getMarkers();
```

And include the following in the server code Code.gs.

```
function getMarkers() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Name");
    var markers = [{lat:ss.getRange('D2').getValue(),lng:ss.getRange('E2').getValue()}];
    return markers;
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in getMarkers: "+err);
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the changes and it is not finding the getMarkers code here is a copy of my code.gs. Could you assist me with what changes I need to make to it.

Comment: Did you edit your `<script>` code as shown?  And you need to put the "Name" of your sheet.

Comment: Yes I did I added the link to my code.gs but it is skipping over the function and I receive the getMarkers undefined error. Could you look at my code.gs file I attached and let me know if it is in the wrong location? Thanks.

Comment: Did you change `getSheetByName("Name")` where "Name" should be the name of the sheet you want to get the values from?

Comment: Yes I changed it to the name of my sheet called AddressValidation but still getting the getMarkers is not defined

Comment: The execution log shows what error?

Comment: This is the error I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: getMarkers is not defined
    at userCodeAppPanel:62:54

Comment: What is `userCodeAppPanel`?

Comment: It is nothing showing. I will attach an image.